# Why can't I directly access the properties of a custom object that I've assigned to a WinForms Control.Tag property?

Tags: c#, winforms, object-reference

I want to set a Winforms `Control.Tag` property with my custom object `ButtonMetaData` and then access the properties of `ButtonMetaData` using the Control.Tag property. Should work because the Tag property is defined as an object, right? See Figure 1.

However, in order to access the properties of `ButtonMetaData`, I'm forced to assign the `Tag` object to an intermediate object variable (`x` in my example) in order to access the `ButtonMetaData` properties. When I try and access them using the Tag object that has been cast to `ButtonMetaData`, the compiler complains. See Figure 2.

Why can't I directly access the properties of `ButtonMetaData` using the Tag object that has been cast to `ButtonMetaData`?

**Figure 1**

[image: Figure 1]

**Figure 2**

```
public class ButtonMetaData
{
    public bool clickedByUser;
    public bool clickedProgramatically;

    public ButtonMetaData(bool clickedByUser, bool clickedProgramatically)
    {
        this.clickedByUser = clickedByUser;
        this.clickedProgramatically = clickedProgramatically;
    }
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;

    button.Tag = new ButtonMetaData(clickedByUser: true, clickedProgramatically: false);

    //BUILDS OK
    ButtonMetaData x = (ButtonMetaData)button.Tag;
    Console.WriteLine(x.clickedByUser);
    Console.WriteLine(x.clickedProgramatically);
    //BUILDS OK

    //DOESN'T BUILD - error on field clickedByUser and error on field clickedProgramatically
    Console.WriteLine((ButtonMetaData)button.Tag.clickedByUser);
    Console.WriteLine((ButtonMetaData)button.Tag.clickedProgramatically);
    //DOESN'T BUILD - error on field clickedByUser and error on field clickedProgramatically

}
```

Comment: Welcome!  Please don't post images of code.  Wishing you well

Comment: For figure 2, replaced screen shot with code (couldn't fix Figure 1 - need screen shot to show VS tip)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot some brackets. You need to cast `button.Tag` to `ButtonMetaData`. Try this:

```
 Console.WriteLine(((ButtonMetaData)button.Tag).clickedByUser);
```

Without brackets you are casting `button.Tag.clickedByUser` to `ButtonMetaData`...

Comment: Viola! I guess this forces the compiler to resolve (ButtonMetaData)button.Tag) before attempting to find the property within. Thanks

Comment: Now that I think about it, I use this approach often in PowerShell scripts to force the interpreter to resolve chunks of code as needed to make things work.

Comment: @NovaSysEng it's not the same thing. Above is casting. What you are referring to is _reflection_